# Function to create and append ggplots to new list with names from existing list

Tags: r, list, ggplot2

I would like to create a named list containing plots. I create a list from a vector containing unique IDs that I use to filter a master dataframe containing all the info.

I then have a function that I use in lapply to loop through the list of unique IDs to filter the master dataframe and create the plots. I then want to append each plot to an (originally) initialized list and I would like the names of the list entry to be equal to the list value passed in lapply.

My code below creates the plots, however the appended list does not have the corresponding names of the passed list id values.

Do I have the wrong approach? I have seen questions/answer that use names(list) etc. but the list passed into lapply is not named, I want passed list entries to become the names of the new list.

Thanks in advance!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

unique_names = as.list(c("apple", "banana", "carrots"))
listy = list()
dframe = data.frame(x_var = seq(1:9)) %>% 
  mutate(y_var = x_var^3)
temp = data.frame(id = c("apple", "apple", "apple", "banana", "banana", "banana", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots"))
dframe = bind_cols(dframe,
                   temp)

fun_plots = function(my_list,
                     my_df,
                     my_appending_list) {
  a = filter(my_df,
             id == my_list)
  plt = ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = a,
              aes(x = x_var,
                  y = y_var))

  my_appending_list$my_list = plt
}

plot_list = lapply(unique_names,
                   fun_plots,
                   my_df = dframe,
                   my_appending_list = listy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take out the `my_appending_list` argument as it doesn't actually achieve anything at the moment, you aren't modifying the `listy` object within the function. You can just do:

```
fun_plots = function(my_list,
                     my_df) {
    a = filter(my_df,
               id == my_list)
    plt = ggplot() +
        geom_line(data = a,
                  aes(x = x_var,
                      y = y_var))

    plt
}

plot_list = lapply(unique_names,
                   fun_plots,
                   my_df = dframe)
names(plot_list) = unique_names
```

Comment: lapply is populating alist with `fun_plots` so I don't need `listy`...thank you! Is there a way to set the name of the list elements within `fun_plots`? I would assume not because lapply is creating the list elements using `fun_plots`...is that thinking correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid writing a function and mutating a list with a little bit more `dplyr` magic. If I understand correctly you want a separate plot object for each value of the "id" variable - if so you can perform a `group_by` on "id" and then generate a ggplot object for each set. Here's how

```
plot_df <- dframe %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  do(plot = ggplot(.data) + geom_line(aes(x = x_var, y = y_var)) + ggtitle(.data$id))
plot_df
#> Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>        id     plot
#> *  <fctr>   <list>
#> 1   apple <S3: gg>
#> 2  banana <S3: gg>
#> 3 carrots <S3: gg>
```

You can facet on the id variables to have one ggplot2. For instance:

```
ggplot(dframe) + geom_line(aes(x = x_var, y = y_var)) + facet_wrap(~ id)
```

Comment: That's pretty awesome seeing as I had no idea that existed! Thanks! I'm actually plotting in `knitr`(latex) which is why I wanted to be able to call the plots using `listname$plotname` so I could visually tell which plots to plot from the list and where.

Comment: Yeah @Prevost, depending on what you're trying to do you might be better off with one plot. The nice thing with `facet_grid` and `facet_wrap` (both part of ggplot2) is they'll label each panel by the value of the variable you facet on - for example you'll have a panel named "apple", "banana", and "carrots". This might be easier unless you need to actually have three separate plots.

Comment: I think what I would do next time is use the `dplyr` `do` function to create all the plots in the data frame and then create a list with each entry equal to the row and call the ggplot from there...and then set the names of the list equal to the data frame column of unique names...I believe there would be a way to accomplish all of that without creating a custom function, by using what already exists!

Comment: Was just working on another project and tried both your methods which worked well. It is very applicable if trying to show a larger number of plots in the appendix (which no one reads...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dplyr group_by to accomplish this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

unique_names = as.list(c("apple", "banana", "carrots"))
listy = list()
dframe = data.frame(x_var = seq(1:9)) %>% 
  mutate(y_var = x_var^3)
temp = data.frame(id = c("apple", "apple", "apple", "banana", "banana", "banana", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots"))
dframe = bind_cols(dframe,
                   temp)

dframe <- group_by(dframe, id) %>% do(plots=ggplot(data=.) +
                              aes(x=x_var, y=y_var) + geom_line() + ggtitle(unique(.$id)))

mylist <- as.list(dframe$plots)

mylist
```

HTH James